# Catching exception in function thrown from its arguments

Tags: c++, function, exception, c++11

```
void foo(int arg);
int foo2() {throw std::out_of_range("error!"); return 5;}

//Now I do this like that:
try { foo(foo2()); }
catch(std::out_of_range) {}
```

And what I want to do, is to catch the exception inside the foo function. However I have no idea how can I put try block in the arguments list?

Comment: You can't, the exception is thrown before the execution of foo started. You need to let foo call foo2 itself for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of time, I prefer @iagreen's solution. But in his/her solution, there is a *dependence issue*:

- should `foo` know `foo2`'s signature?

Of course we can get some conclusions in your original call `foo(foo2())`

1. the return value of `foo2` should be *convertible to int*
2. `foo` does not need to know the amount of `foo2`'s arguments nor their types, even what's the function invoked before `foo`

So I think a implementation by ***Variadic Template*** is more suitable in most cases.

```
template < typename F, typename... Args >
void foo( F f, Args&&... args ) {
    int ret = f( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    std::cout << "ret = " << ret << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant, because the exception isnt thrown before `foo()` was executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You either need to pull the call to `foo2` out of the call to `foo`, and handle the exception in the calling routine, as such --

```
int param;
try { 
   param = foo2(); 
} catch(std::out_of_range) {}
foo(param);
```

or pass `foo2` as a function to `foo`, and evaluate it inside `foo`, like this --

```
void foo(int (*arg_func)()) {
  int arg;
  try { 
    arg = arg_func();
   } catch(std::out_of_range) {
    std::cout << "out of range ";
   }
}
```

the call then looks like this --

```
foo(foo2);
```

Of course, now you always have to pass a function to `foo`, no literals or expressions.